# How to pass data from one class to another while making it mutable in Flutter?

Tags: class, inheritance, dart, flutter

I am new to Flutter. As of now when I pass data between Stateful Classes the data becomes immutable for the receiving class. This should help be re-render widgets in both classes whenever ever one class updates the data.

How does inheritance work in flutter so that I can make data mutable between classes ? Can someone explain this with a sample code example.

Comment: Honestly, I have been mutating inherited data, because it only gives me a warning and not an error, but I'm curious what the proper way of doing this as well.